# .SWF Images on Android Native Application

Tags: android, flash, native

I am working on android native applications and I want to show a .swf file which is a flash content. I am using HTML5 and this is a simple code to show the swf file

The above code works in all desktop browsers because the browsers have the default adobe flash plugin installed.
But if the same code is run as android application I just see a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible in android.

You can open a browser or webview and show the swf file from SDCard as:

```
 file://sdcard/filename.swf
```